# R tm, plugin.sentiment packages: how to plot sentiment trending?

Tags: r, sentiment-analysis, tm

My Objective:
Select a stock ticker, plot candlestick plot with stock trend for it. 
Access news for the same stock ticker and plot sentiment analysis trends for it to visually correlate the trends.

```
library(XML)
library(tm)
library(tm.plugin.webmining)
library(tm.plugin.sentiment)  
library(NLP)
library(openNLP)
library(slam)
library(tm.plugin.tags)
library(SnowballC) 

#Get stock time series for selected stock
getSymbols("XYZ", src="yahoo")
chartSeries(XYZ, subset='last 3 months')
addBBands() ### This plots last 3 months of stock trending chart
#Get news for the specific stock
XYZNews = WebCorpus(GoogleFinanceSource("XYZ"))
text.corpus = score(XYZNews)
meta(text.corpus)
```

Now my objective is to save all the news articles in a time series and plot sentiment, polarity etc for the specific stock based on daily news corpus to compare it visually with QuantMod plotted stock trending charts.

Question: I came across chartSentiment {tm.plugin.sentiment} but not sure how to use it.
chartSentiment(xts, prefix = "SEMNT",
its XTS Object Containing at minimum 'Close' and 'Score' fields

Not able to find any examples as well. Appreciate any help from the community.

Comment: While your title includes the package names it would be advisable to include the `library` calls in your code as well.

Comment: You are right. Here are the packages:

Comment: library(XML)
    library(tm)
    library(tm.plugin.webmining)
    library(tm.plugin.sentiment)
    library(NLP)
    library(openNLP)
    library(slam)
    library(tm.plugin.tags)
    library(SnowballC)

Comment: thanks Tyler for reformat. I am new to the community and still getting used to formats.